# R Reshape Performance

Tags: r, performance, reshape

EDIT: In creating a simple sample data.frame I used the same dates for the two Date columns however this is not the case, which makes this problem harder.

Instead of this dataframe:

```
ID     Date           Balance    Date2        Balance2
1      01-01-2014     10000      01-02-2014   5000
2      01-01-2014     50000      01-02-2014   30000
3      01-01-2014     30000      01-02-2014   15000 
4      01-01-2014     5000       01-02-2014   3500
```

I have this dataframe instead:

```
ID     Date           Balance    Date2        Balance2
1      01-01-2014     10000      01-02-2017   5000
2      01-01-2015     50000      01-02-2016   30000
3      01-08-2014     30000      01-02-2015   15000 
4      01-02-2016     5000       01-02-2018   3500
```

Which I would like to reshape to the following:

```
ID     Date           Balance
1      01-01-2014     10000      
1      02-02-2017     5000
2      01-01-2015     50000      
2      01-02-2016     30000      
3      ...            ...        And so on...
```

I have the following at the moment.

```
Dates = a character containing all the columns with Dates (Date, Date2, Date3...)
Balances = a character containing all the columns with Balances (Balance1, Balance2...)

df <- reshape(df,
               varying = Balances,
               v.names = "Balance"
               timevar = "Date"
               times = Dates,
               direction = "long")
```

The results with your excellently proposed methods does not get me the results when I changed my sample data.frame / data.table.

The main problem is that I have different dates in the dates column, there is no way I can change this. Date1 - Date2 - Date3 are always in chronological order though.

I need a way where R understands it needs to take the Date column and the Balance column, place it in a new DF, then take Date2 and Balance2, rbind them with the first DF, then Date3, Balance3 and so on, until I got my 700ish variables.

I'm thinking of writing a loop, any thoughts? See below for sample data.

Thanks in advance,

Robert

```
df <- data.frame(ID=seq(1:4),
                Date= c("01-01-2014","01-01-2015","01-08-2014","01-02-2016"),
                Balance = c(10000,50000,30000,5000),
                Date2= c("01-02-2017","01-02-2016","01-02-2015","01-02-2018"),
            Balance2 = c(5000,30000,15000,3500))
```

Comment: I can’t comment on your specific problem but I urge you to switch to `reshape2`, which comes with a vastly improved API, and is implemented in C++ which comes with potentially dramatic performance improvements.

Comment: @RobertLuyt, see my edit. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

If your columns are named as you've provided in your example, you can try `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package. Note that the values in your "ID" column must be unique to work correctly though (as they are in your sample data).

Usage is straightforward: Specify the "stubs" of the variables (here, "Date" and "Balance"). Setting `sep = "var.stubs"` just strips out the rest of the column name. the `[, .time_1 := NULL]` is just to drop the time column that was created in the reshaping process.

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = c("Date", "Balance"), 
             sep = "var.stubs")[, .time_1 := NULL][]
#    ID       Date Balance
# 1:  1 01-01-2014   10000
# 2:  1 01-02-2014    5000
# 3:  2 01-01-2014   50000
# 4:  2 01-02-2014   30000
# 5:  3 01-01-2014   30000
# 6:  3 01-02-2014   15000
# 7:  4 01-01-2014    5000
# 8:  4 01-02-2014    3500
```

Soon (version 1.9.8 of "data.table") `melt` would be able to handle conversion to a semi-long form like you're trying to get here. That would be faster than `merged.stack` presently is, but `merged.stack` should already be able to handle your present scenario.

Comment: Hi Ananda -- Do you have some reference that mentions/describes that upcoming enhancement of `data.table::melt()`?  Scratch that: [found it](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/828)! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, Just got pinged on this comment. Strange.... Glad you found the reference in the meantime :-) Perhaps a little embarrassing to say it, but I'm excited by this development :-)

Comment: Hah! That means there are at least two of us ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the easiest solution to build a new data.frame by combining the two column sets? This can be done without `reshape`:

```
r> x <- data.frame(ID=1:4, Date=as.POSIXct(c('2014-01-01','2014-01-01','2014-01-01','2014-01-01')), Balance=c(10000,50000,30000,5000), Date2=as.POSIXct(c('2014-01-02','2014-01-02','2014-01-02','2014-01-02')), Balance2=c(5000,30000,15000,3500) );
r> y <- data.frame(ID=c(x$ID,x$ID), Date=c(x$Date,x$Date2), Balance=c(x$Balance,x$Balance2) );
r> y;
  ID       Date Balance
1  1 2014-01-01   10000
2  2 2014-01-01   50000
3  3 2014-01-01   30000
4  4 2014-01-01    5000
5  1 2014-01-02    5000
6  2 2014-01-02   30000
7  3 2014-01-02   15000
8  4 2014-01-02    3500
```

Can you let me know if this performs well for your data?

For sorting:

```
r> z <- y[order(y$ID,y$Date),]; rownames(z) <- 1:nrow(z);
r> z;
  ID       Date Balance
1  1 2014-01-01   10000
2  1 2014-01-02    5000
3  2 2014-01-01   50000
4  2 2014-01-02   30000
5  3 2014-01-01   30000
6  3 2014-01-02   15000
7  4 2014-01-01    5000
8  4 2014-01-02    3500
```

**Edit:** Considering you have so many columns, manually calling `c()` on each respective Date and Balance column is not practical. However, after playing around a bit, I realized you can combine the `names()`, `grep()`, `do.call()`, and `c()` functions to automatically extract and combine your data exactly the way you want. You will also need `unname()` to remove undesired element names, and `replicate()` to replicate the ID column a sufficient number of times.

First, I figured out a way to generate a randomized input data.frame for testing:

```
r> randDate <- function() as.Date('2014-01-01')+as.integer(runif(1,max=30));
r> randBalance <- function() 5000+as.integer(runif(1,max=18))*5000;
r> n <- 700;
r> x <- setNames(do.call(data.frame, c(list(1:4), replicate(n, list(do.call(c, replicate(4, randDate(), simplify=F ) ), do.call(c, replicate(4, randBalance(), simplify=F ) ) ), simplify=F ) ) ), c('ID', sapply(1:n, function(x) c(paste0('Date',x), paste0('Balance',x) ) ) ) );
r> x;
  ID      Date1 Balance1      Date2 Balance2      Date3 Balance3 ... Balance698    Date699 Balance699    Date700 Balance700
1  1 2014-01-29    10000 2014-01-08    50000 2014-01-05    40000 ...      30000 2014-01-23      35000 2014-01-08      45000
2  2 2014-01-30    65000 2014-01-15    10000 2014-01-11    45000 ...      75000 2014-01-29      25000 2014-01-04      50000
3  3 2014-01-11    75000 2014-01-14    70000 2014-01-24    45000 ...      50000 2014-01-02      10000 2014-01-01      50000
4  4 2014-01-11    25000 2014-01-11    20000 2014-01-24    20000 ...      50000 2014-01-08      70000 2014-01-11      75000
```

Now, you can achieve the desired reshaping using the following:

```
r> y <- data.frame(ID=do.call(c, replicate((ncol(x)-1)/2, x$ID, simplify=F ) ), Date=unname(do.call(c, x[,grep('^Date[0-9]+$', names(x) )] )), Balance=unname(do.call(c, x[,grep('^Balance[0-9]+$', names(x) )] )) );
r> y;
     ID       Date Balance
1     1 2014-01-29   10000
2     2 2014-01-30   65000
3     3 2014-01-11   75000
4     4 2014-01-11   25000
5     1 2014-01-08   50000
6     2 2014-01-15   10000
...
2795  3 2014-01-02   10000
2796  4 2014-01-08   70000
2797  1 2014-01-08   45000
2798  2 2014-01-04   50000
2799  3 2014-01-01   50000
2800  4 2014-01-11   75000
```

And for ordering:

```
r> z <- y[order(y$ID,y$Date),]; rownames(z) <- 1:nrow(z);
r> z;
     ID       Date Balance
1     1 2014-01-01   55000
2     1 2014-01-01   20000
3     1 2014-01-01   15000
4     1 2014-01-01   75000
5     1 2014-01-01   40000
6     1 2014-01-01   85000
...
2795  4 2014-01-30   15000
2796  4 2014-01-30   65000
2797  4 2014-01-30    5000
2798  4 2014-01-30   70000
2799  4 2014-01-30   35000
2800  4 2014-01-30   30000
```

This code runs basically instantly. The key to the speed is that it extracts each input column for a target output column at the same time by subscripting the data.frame (e.g. `x[,grep('^Date[0-9]+$', names(x) )]` for all Date columns) and runs all of them through a single call to `c()` via a single call to `do.call`, which ignores the data.frame class of the argument and just treats it as the underlying list that it is. The end result is that you get a `c()`-combined vector of the output column in a form that is *almost* ready for attaching to the output data.frame (you just have to remove the unwanted element names using `unname()`). You need to do this for the Date columns and Balance columns independently (Balance columns subscripted via `x[,grep('^Balance[0-9]+$', names(x) )]`), and package them together in a new data.frame construction call. The only other piece of the puzzle is to replicate the input ID column a sufficient number of times (`(ncol(x)-1)/2`) to generate the correct output ID column that corresponds with the Date and Balance output vectors.

This solution is completely vectorized, with no explicit or hidden loops. Also, it only uses built-in R functionality; it does not require dependence on any add-on packages. I always try to avoid using add-on packages, which tend to add complexity and maintenance difficulties later on, as the breadth of knowledge required to understand the code increases.

Comment: And then you get what the questionner requested you could order by ID. That ordering may be a bit of a slow bit.

Comment: or `rbind(DF[, 1:3], DF[, c(1, 4:5)])`

Comment: @Roland, I like the concision of your suggestion, but when I run it I get `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names`, and `rbind()` doesn't seem to provide any way to specify names. Is there a way to make `rbind()` work?

Comment: `rbind(setNames(DF[, 1:3], c("ID", "Date", "Balance")), setNames(DF[, c(1, 4:5)], c("ID", "Date", "Balance")))`

Comment: For this particular case, can improve it slightly to `rbind(x[,1:3],setNames(x[,c(1,4:5)],names(x[,1:3])))`.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about order than probably the fastest method will come from `data.table` answers. But if you don't then you could just bind the rows of the first three columns with the first and last two using `rbind`. That will be very fast and simple but not have the order you desire. You can reorder with the `order` function on ID.

Alternatively you could generate two matrices, transpose, and then bind it all together as vectors. This will be pretty fast because you're just making a few copies and selections and the reordering is done through just identifying the data in a different way rather than relying on a sorting algorithm.

```
dateMat <- as.matrix(df[, c(2, 4)])
balMat  <- as.matrix(df[, c(3, 5)])
dates <- as.vector( t(dateMat) )
balances <- as.vector( t(balMat) )
dfl <- data.frame(ID = rep(df$ID, each = 2), Date = dates, Balance = balances)
```

You can test the two versions out for speed on your large `data.frame`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be the following. Using `select` in `dplyr`, you can choose columns and change column names at the same time. You bind the two data sets with `bind_rows` in the end.

DATA & CODE

```
mydf <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "01-01-2014", class = "factor"), 
Balance = c(10000L, 50000L, 30000L, 5000L), Date2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "01-02-2014", class = "factor"), Balance2 = c(5000L, 
30000L, 15000L, 3500L)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "Balance", 
"Date2", "Balance2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

# Convert factor to date object
mutate_each(mydf, funs(as.Date(., format = "%m-%d-%Y")), Date, Date2) -> mydf

bind_rows(select(mydf, 1:3), select(mydf, 1, Date = Date2, Balance = Balance2)) %>%
arrange(ID, Date)

#  ID       Date Balance
#1  1 2014-01-01   10000
#2  1 2014-01-02    5000
#3  2 2014-01-01   50000
#4  2 2014-01-02   30000
#5  3 2014-01-01   30000
#6  3 2014-01-02   15000
#7  4 2014-01-01    5000
#8  4 2014-01-02    3500
```

Comment: @RobertLuyt You got all kinds of great approaches here. Try them all and see what works for you best. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` solution.  I'm still trying to think how to remove calls to the first data.table.

```
dt <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "01-01-2014", class = "factor"), 
Balance = c(10000L, 50000L, 30000L, 5000L), Date2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "01-02-2014", class = "factor"), Balance2 = c(5000L, 
30000L, 15000L, 3500L)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "Balance", 
"Date2", "Balance2"), class = "data.table", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

dt1 <- melt(dt,id="ID",measure=c("Balance","Balance2"))[, variable := c(as.character(dt$Date), as.character(dt$Date2))]
dt1
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28563985/3817004), version 1.9.6 of `data.table` (on CRAN 19 Sep 2015) has introduced the ability to melt into multiple columns:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = patterns("Date", "Balance"), 
     value.name = c("Date", "Balance"))
```

> ```
>    ID variable       Date Balance
> 1:  1        1 01-01-2014   10000
> 2:  2        1 01-01-2015   50000
> 3:  3        1 01-08-2014   30000
> 4:  4        1 01-02-2016    5000
> 5:  1        2 01-02-2017    5000
> 6:  2        2 01-02-2016   30000
> 7:  3        2 01-02-2015   15000
> 8:  4        2 01-02-2018    3500
> ```